# Why date format is not changed in datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have used jquery-ui-1.7.2 datepicker in my code. I want to change the date in 'yy-mm-dd' format. But It doesn't change and takes default value.

Here is my code:

```
<div  id='myDate'>
 <input type="text" id="monthInput" class="form-control" name="water.month"  value="${water?.month}"  />
  </div>
```

and jquery:

```
  var now = new Date();
        var prevMonthFirstDate = new Date(now.getFullYear() - (now.getMonth() > 0 ? 0 : 1), (now.getMonth() - 1 + 12) % 12, 1);
        var prevMonthLastDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 0);
        $('#monthInput').datepicker({

            altFormat: 'yy-MM-dd',
            dateFormat: 'yy-MM-dd',
            startDate: prevMonthFirstDate,
            endDate: prevMonthLastDate
        });
```

[image: screenshot is attached]

What should I do?

Comment: _Which_ datepicker …?

Comment: it's jquery 1.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Use dateFormat property instead of altFormat

```
    $('#monthInput').datepicker({

        dateFormat: 'yy-MM-dd'
    });
```

Comment: try it now with out startDate and endDate

Comment: @OUNAsh  datepicked version and jQuery library version?

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault. I have used bootstrap datepicker, not jquery datepicker. To change it, I have done this:

```
 var now = new Date();
        var prevMonthFirstDate = new Date(now.getFullYear() - (now.getMonth() > 0 ? 0 : 1), (now.getMonth() - 1 + 12) % 12, 1);
        var prevMonthLastDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 0);
        $('#monthInput').datepicker({

            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            startDate: prevMonthFirstDate,
            endDate: prevMonthLastDate
        });
```